CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing
I am writing my code in django python, Here is my view.py
@csrf_exempt
@api_view(['POST'])
def Userlogin1(request):
    print('login working')
    username = request.data.get('username')
    password = request.data.get('password')
    user = authenticate(request=request._request, username = username, password = password)
    if user is not None:
        login(request._request, user)
        return Response({'message': 'login successful.'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response({'error': 'Invalid credentials.', 'user':user, 'username':username, 'password':password}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)

when i run this on the postman, on first POST request, postman returning a correct response <'message': 'login successful.> but on second and further hit, post man throwing 403 error with this message {
"detail": "CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing."
}
after removing the cookies from postman, it can run once but shows again same issue

I disabled the csrf token
added CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS
created custom


You could try re-ordering the decorators.  Also, if you're only doing API stuff, you could remove the CSRF middleware, but that would remove protection from all views.

So do you hit the same view the second time, or another one?
